# Iterate a user string in bash to add vowels to string

Tags: bash, loops, unix, cpu-word

So I have a word list containing over 30,000 words. My goals is to make a script that takes in a word without constants in it (example: mbnt), and somehow add constants and compare to the word list to find atleast the word "ambient", though it will also find other words that would read as "mbnt" if you were to take out all of their vowels.
So far this is my bash script

```
f=/wordList
anyVowel=[aAeEiIoOuU]
nonVowel=[^aAeEiIoOuU]
input=$1
for (( i=0; i<${#input}; i++ ));
do
grep "${input:$i:1}$nonVowel" $f | head -10
done
```

however this will just return a just a normal list of words with some of the characters the user inputs. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, you are trying to do data processing in `bash`.

Comment: One thing that's going wrong is that the input characters are being searched for one at a time.  They need to be searched for all together, in the correct order.  Also, they need to be mixed with vowels, not non-vowels.  It might make sense to mix them with non-consonants if the word list includes punctuation.  Then `don't` would match for `dnt`.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v w=whr '{a=tolower($0); 
                 gsub(/[^a-z]/,"",a); 
                 gsub(/[aeiou]/,"",a)} 
                a==w' words

where
```

looking for the vowels dropped word "whr" in the words (make up a custom dict). Convert to lowercase, filter out non alphas and remove vowels, finally look for a match with the given word.

Note that this is very inefficient if you're looking for many words, but perhaps can be a template for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
wordsfile=wordList
consonants=$1

# Create a regular expression that matches the input consonants with
# any number of vowels before, after, or between them
regex='^[[:space:]]*[aeiou]*'
for (( i=0; i<${#consonants}; i++ )) ; do
    regex+="${consonants:i:1}[aeiou]*"
done
regex+='[[:space:]]*$'

grep -i -- "$regex" "$wordsfile"
```